# Udev rule: ACTION=="add" is working, but ACTION=="remove" isn't working!

Tags: udev, trisquel

I've written file `90-usb.rules` under `/etc/udev/rules.d/` containing:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTR{idProduct}=="2008", RUN+="/bin/mkdir /home/pandya/Desktop/testdir"
ACTION=="remove", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTR{idProduct}=="2008", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /home/pandya/Desktop/testdir"
```

When I plugged in device udev `ACTION=="add"` creates directory by means of `RUN+="/bin/mkdir /home/pandya/Desktop/testdir"` (which works fine)

**BUT** when I unplugged device similar udev `ACTION=="remove` **doesn't** removes directory by means of `RUN+="/bin/rmdir /home/pandya/Desktop/testdir"`

<sub>There is no problem with `/bin/rmdir` because I've also checked by replacing it with another `mkdir` (`RUN+="/bin/mkdir /home/pandya/Desktop/testdir2"`) but this also not working.</sub>

So, I want to know that Why **removal action** is not working? How do I fix it?

Comment: @don_crissti Yes, action by using `ENV` is working. I tried `ENV{ID_MODEL}` which is working fine. Thank-you (BTW if you are interested to post answer, then ask me to add `udevadm monitor --property` output in question OR I will continue for answer?)

Comment: @don_crissti [Done!](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178453/66803)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<sub>As per [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/udev-not-doing-remove-rules-841733/) suggestion, (here) commented by [@don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178341/udev-rule-action-add-is-working-but-action-remove-isnt-working#comment296314_178341) I am providing solution that worked for me.</sub>

---

Following is output of `udevadm monitor --property` while removing device (KERNEL lines are skipped and only last UDEV remove is attached below)

```
UDEV  [1380.287343] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4 (usb)
ACTION=remove
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/013
DEVNUM=013
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=Micromax_A74
ID_MODEL_ENC=Micromax\x20A74
ID_MODEL_ID=2008
ID_REVISION=0255
ID_SERIAL=MediaTek_Micromax_A74_0123456789ABCDEF
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0123456789ABCDEF
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ffff00:
ID_VENDOR=MediaTek
ID_VENDOR_ENC=MediaTek
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)
ID_VENDOR_ID=0bb4
MAJOR=189
MINOR=12
PRODUCT=bb4/2008/255
SEQNUM=2017
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=446266
```

From above I've used Environment **`ID_MODEL`**`=Micromax_A74` in my udev rule for `ACTION=="remove"` and now udev rule becomes:

```
ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Micromax_A74", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /home/pandya/Desktop/testdir"
```

Now it is removing `testdir` by means of `ACTION=="remove"`

Hence, The solution is: **Use suitable environment such as `ID_MODEL` instead of `ATTR{idVendor}` & `ATTR{idProduct}` in `ACTION=="remove"`**

Comment: What an ...interesting caveat... :( Thanks udev! And thanks @Pandya :)